# ContentView for tableViewCell not auto-resizing correctly?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, snapkit

I have added 2 labels to my cell and setup these constraints with snapkit, issue is I cant get the cell to expand correctly, it stays at its default height:

```
titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(contentView.snp.top)
        make.bottom.equalTo(descriptionLabel.snp.top)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView.snp.left)
        make.right.equalTo(contentView.snp.right)
    }
    descriptionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom)
        make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp.bottom)
        make.left.equalTo(contentView.snp.left)
        make.right.equalTo(contentView.snp.right)
    }
```

I mapped the four edges as you can see, however I know height isnt implied by these, how can I apply a height when the content is by nature, dynamic, and could be various heights...

setup for the labels looks like this:

```
 lazy var titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.textColor = .green
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    return titleLabel
}()

lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
    descriptionLabel.textColor = .dark
    descriptionLabel.textAlignment = .center
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
    return descriptionLabel
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the table view an `estimatedRowHeight`, and set its `rowHeight` to UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Now the cells will be self-sizing. Well, if a label is pinned by all four sides to the content view, and if the cell is self-sizing, then that's all you have to do: the label will *automatically* change its height to accommodate its text, and the cell will *automatically* change size to accommodate the label.

Comment: Downloadable example project here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p424variableHeights

Comment: yeah so what ive done is correct then? but it doesnt work! the cell retains its size

Comment: Hey, I showed you _my_ code, and it _does_ work. Download the project and see! You have not shown your code (I don't know how the table view is configured) so who knows what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that you should add subviews to contentView in subclassed UITableViewCell class initializer method.

```
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
           super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
           self.contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
           self.contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)
}
```

Secondly, make sure that in your viewDidLoad method (probably in your ViewController) these two lines are added:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Of course, you should change estimatedRowHeight to accommodate your needs.

One more thing worth mentioning - you can create these constraints easier (using power of SnapKit):

```
titleLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.left.right.equalTo(contentView)
}
descriptionLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
    make.top.equalTo(titleLabel.snp.bottom)
    make.bottom.left.right.equalTo(contentView)
}
```